# jquery datatable enabling "searching" shows no record

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have multiple datatables across my application. Some of them has dynamic "aoColumns" and some of them has normal source. In one of the datatables when I enable searching it works fine on first load but If I visit other data tables coming back to this one then it will show no matching record. see the screenshot for details.

```
 $.when(awx.data.USERS.manageusers(), awx.data.USERS.getLastLoginTimes())
    .done(function (data1, data2) {
        var data = $.Enumerable.From(data1[0]).Select(function (v) {
            var ll = arr = jQuery.grep(data2[0], function( a ) {
                return v.Email == a.Email
            });
            v["LastAccessDate"] = ll.length > 0 ? ll[0].LastAccessDateTimeUTC : null;
            return v;
        }).ToArray();

        var content = awx.util.applyTemplate("manageusers");
        $('#main-content').html(content);

        $('#manageusers_table').DataTable({
           data: data,               
           "aoColumns": [
            { "data": "name"},
            { "data": "Email" },
            { "data": "role"},
            { "data": "org"},
            { "data": "date" },
            { "data": "accDate" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "workingstatus"}
        });
```

[image]

Comment: it works good on first visit before visiting other datatables but after visiting other datatables it shows no record. see the attached image for details.

Comment: Sounds like it isnt refreshed?

Comment: if I add "searching": false; as a datatable setting it works totally fine. By default searching is on and I need it on too but this issue when it is on.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't refresh your `data` object and all datatables use the same data.

Try to use **ajax method** to retrieve your data again:

```
$('#manageusers_table').DataTable( {
                paging: true,
                ordering: true,
                info: true,
                bSort: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("ControllerName","ActionName")', //ASP.NET MVC
                bProcessing: true
} );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you see in my question there is a data: data  property for datatable. each time I view this data table I get a new copy of data from server.  I don't have an ajax source in here.

Comment: as you can see on image attached, the count is 1483+. that means my object has data but not showing and don't know why. thanks

Comment: You must paste the whole JS code. From your post we can only guess.

Comment: see the updated code on questions. thanks for looking into this.

Comment: The real problem is that you create new `datatable` objects again and again. Create that object only once:

`var MyTable = $('#manageusers_table').DataTable({ ... });`

and than use something like this:

`.done(function (data) {
                MyTable.fnClearTable();
                MyTable.fnAddData(data);
                MyTable.fnDraw();
        });`

Comment: well, here is how I solved it. adding this two lines    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.length = 0;
mydatatable.fnDraw();

Answer (score 0):

so, here is how I finally solved it or maybe worked around it.
Assigned my datatable to a variable and then these two lines.

```
     var dtable =   $('#manageusers_table').DataTable({...
        });
        $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.length = 0;
        dtable.fnDraw();
```